# Is there a tehilim in Hebrew or English with amazing commentaries?

Tags: product-recommendation, tehilim-psalms

I'm looking for a tehilim with commentaries that are melaket from commentaries like the Alter Rebbe or Reb Nachman or any of the chassidic masters. I don't mind if it is in Hebrew or English.

Is there one available?

Answer (score 3):

[Kehot](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=EP-TEHI.DEL) offers a English version of Tehillim  by Rabbi Yosef B. Marcus, including various commentaries (Radak, Alshich, Metzudos etc..). This version also includes commentaries from various chassidic masters. See also [here](https://www.chabad.org/news/article_cdo/aid/3540642/jewish/New-Edition-of-Psalms-A-Beautiful-Bridge-Between-Supplication-and-Study.htm) for a quick review.

Then there is a Hebrew version called אמרות טהורות על ספר תהלים (Sefer Amarot Maḥberet Ha-Kodesh Al Sefer Tehilim) by Eliezer ben Jacob. You can view it [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=S9Y7AQAAMAAJ&lpg=PA5&ots=T88u9U8DM1&dq=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%98%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&hl=nl&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%98%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&f=false) (However, it does not includes commentaries from the Alter Rebbe...).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously he was not Chassidic, but THE HIRSCH TEHILLIM of Rav Samson Raphael Hirsch is excellent. Indeed I have read numerous other commentaries by respected ravs, scholars and other authors and they cite Rav Hirsch's commentary extensively and continuously. I highly recommend it. Good luck in your search and Shabbat Shalom.

Answer (score 1):

[Tehilim Hameforash](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/tehilim-hameforash-kollel-mavo-hosafos-vehearos/36088?gclid=CjwKCAjw7IeUBhBbEiwADhiEMXPMQj2J7YaNSPbzLTr54sqsPpSPr0MDyP-zV_0rClgoe1eWBI02GRoCQKIQAvD_BwE)  By Rabbi Yakov Weingarten. Amazing explanation of each verse. He also notes all his sources. It is not specifically a Chassidic work, but being the Rabbi Weingarten is Chassidic, he doesn't shy away from such sources.

Answer (score 1):

Keren Odesser put out a [Tehillim](https://everythingbreslov.com/tehilim-with-likutei-halachos.html) with a yalkut of the Likutei Halachos from Reb Noson miBreslov on it. It's excellent.

They also have a [smaller-size edition](https://everythingbreslov.com/tehilim-with-likutei-halachos-new-medium-size-edition.html), if you'd prefer that.